# Adding popups to leaflet routing machine waypoint markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

```
 route = L.Routing.control({
                 waypoints: test
        }).addTo(map);
```

I am using leaflet routing machine. Test is an array of L.latlng(float, float). I would like to add a popup with a message to each individual waypoint marker. Any idea how i could go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
L.Routing.control({
        createMarker: function(waypointIndex, waypoint, numberOfWaypoints) {
            return L.marker(wp.latLng)
                .bindPopup('Hello');
        },
        ...
    }
```